# Particularly difficult sequence identification relating to information transfer

Tags: sequences-and-series, information-theory

I first became interested in this problem when my brother, in secondary school, was asked to determine the nth term of a particularly challenging sequence, got stuck, and showed it to me. The question stated that there were $n$ weather stations, each with their own piece of data that they had collected, and each weather station had to know every piece of data. The question stated that they were to use phone calls to transfer the data, so that the two weather stations in the call could synchronise the information they had. The sequence was to be generated from the fewest number of calls needed to synchronise the data of $n$ weather stations.

For example, if A calls B, now both A and B have data AB. If B were to then call C, A would have AB, B would have ABC and C ABC likewise. I quickly determined that the upper bound of this sequence would be $n!$, which dropped to $n^2$ with further thought. Edit: The upper bound of calls needed has dropped to $(n-1)^2$ with help from Mindlack. However, I couldn't help my brother with his homework (of GCSE standard) so we dropped the matter.

I maintained interest, so I generated this table of values, $c$ and $n$, which is correct to the best of my ability:
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline n & c \\ \hline 0 & undefined \\ \hline 1 & 0 \\ \hline 2 & 1 \\ \hline 3 & 3 \\ \hline 4 & 4 \\ \hline 5 & 8 \\ \hline 6 & 10 \\ \hline 7 & 11 \\ \hline 8 & 12 \\ \hline  \end{array}

I noticed that the powers of two followed the rule $c = $ $0.5$ $n$ $log_2(n)$, but I still had no rule for finding the other terms.I reached out to my maths teacher (A level), and we went over it together. He was totally stumped however, and I was having trouble hand generating efficient solutions for higher values of $n$.

I am almost positive that this sequence must have been generated before, especially in the information theory branches of mathematics, as the idea of sharing data over a two way connection would be well researched. When I googled it, I only found reference to $0.5$ $n$ $log_2(n)$ in matrix multiplication and computational complexity.

Could someone help me find the elusive $n$th term formula for this sequence, or point me to where this sequence has been generated before?

Comment: Isn't there a (suboptimal according to your table, but still linear) strategy where A calls everyone (so gets all the information) and then recalls everyone (to share it)? Or is there a constraint I missed?

Comment: I think I have a 11-call strategy for seven stations. Call them A,B,C,D,E,F,G. Let A call B,C (so that A knows ABC), let D call E,F,G (so that D knows DEFG), let A call D (so that A and D have full information), and then A calls B,C, and D calls E,F,G again.

Comment: It seems like i must have messed up on the n=7 case, and no, there is no constraint stopping your idea

Comment: If it’s this sequence http://oeis.org/A239976 (the positions of the $n$-th $1$ in the binary representation of $\log 2$), a formula seems unlikely. If $\log 2$ is “normal,” (which I couldn’t verify with quick googling, but imagine is true), then the $n$-th term would be approximately $2n$.

Comment: By generalizing the strategy I outlined, I think it follows that $c(n)-2n$ is nonincreasing. Not sure if this can lead to a full formula. So we find $c(n) \leq 2n-3$. But what's your strategy with $n=4$? I can't find any 4-call strategy with 4 stations...

Comment: Have you tried interpolating the function $c(n)$ using Finite Differences or Lagrange Interpolation?

WolframAlpha gives the following polynomial interpolating with $n = x = 1$ to $8$:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator%22%2C+%22data2%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%7D%2C%7B3%2C3%7D%2C%7B4%2C4%7D%2C%7B5%2C8%7D%2C%7B6%2C10%7D%2C%7B7%2C11%7D%2C%7B8%2C12%7D%7D%22

Comment: However, the problem with interpolation is it works for the interpolated range but outside of it, the errors are significant.

Comment: @Mindlack if we have stations ABCD, a calls b, c calls d, a calls c and b calls d

Comment: @SteveKass it does seem odd that the sequence matches, i will have to see how it compares to higher numbers. Binary ones of ln(2) sounds to be the right sort of sequence

Comment: Right. Somehow I had myself convinced that this couldn’t work. So we get the following strat for $n \geq 5$ stations – make four groups of them, each one with a leader (let’s call them A,B,C,D). First, all the members of each group call their leader, so the leader knows all the information of their group. Then A calls B, C calls D, A calls C, B calls D, so A,B,C,D know everything. And then the leaders repropagate their information to their group. That makes $2n-4$ calls.

Comment: It feels like looking at lower bounds is called for. There's the trivial one of $n-1$. More involved (and I haven't checked this properly) - consider looking at the net amount of new information that can be received in any round. For the $t$th call, if $t \le n-1$ then this seems to be at most $t+1$, and of course there's the generic bound of $n$. In total $n(n-1)$ units need to be transmitted, which gives a lower bound of $\sim 3n/2$.

Comment: Having done some more research, it seems that http://oeis.org/A239976 fits perfectly, so if @SteveKass or someone wants to write up an answer as to why that is then I'll mark it correct

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking in the wrong way, but that OEIS sequence has successions like 66,69,72 while I argued that $2n-c(n)$ had to be nondecreasing. So I'm not sure that the sequence fits.

Comment: PS: has anyone an argument why $c(8) > 11$? I can't find a counterexample but the "jumps" of $2n-c(n)$ occur before at powers of two, so it wouldn't be too surprising that $c(8) < 2 \cdot 8-4=12$. But I can't find any strategy...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, as I'm only in year 2 A level, but I can have a guess. As we see here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ztpntdecfm for the lower values, the ones I have calculated by hand (black), $2n - c(n)$ is decreasing, but I'm not sure if you literally mean negative gradient or not

Comment: What I mean is that if $c(n)$ is the minimal number of calls for $n$ stations, then $c(n+1) \leq c(n)+2$ -- simply have the first station call the second, let the $n$ stations (every one but the first one) apply an optimal information-sharing strategy (in $c(n)$ calls) and then have any of them call back the first one (so $c(n)+2$ calls in total). But the OEIS sequence doesn't satisfy this equation. BTW, this shows a 6-call strategy for 5 stations, an 8-call strategy for six stations and a 10-call strategy for 7 stations.

Comment: I've got my head around what you are saying now, and yes, that means that the sequence doesn't fit. I'll see if I can find the optimal solutions now.